# Prevent accidental updates/deletes on any table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

It happened to me a couple of times to accidentally update all records of a production table.
Lack of attention and whatnot...

I've heard in MySQL to be a compile/run time switch to prevent such accidents.
Like, if I would do a

```
UPDATE Table SET Field=0
```

this won't compile/run because of the missing WHERE clause. 
And if you *really* wanted to update all, you could

```
UPDATE Table SET Field=0 WHERE 42=42
```

Any ideas for MS SQL?

I found some answers online referring to a trigger. That would be a little costly I guess.
And it would mean I must put the trigger on every necessary table.

Comment: Easy solution: DONT ALLOW DEVS ACCESS TO PROD!!! We are evil breakers of all things production.

Comment: FYI in MySQL its called *safe update mode* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates - Getting the habit of wrapping statements in a transaction can be helpful.

Comment: One best-practice, is to not execute arbitrary SQL on your Production database. Create a file containing your SQL, execute it against a copy of the production database, and then, assuming it's fine, execute it against your production database.

Comment: Yes, that's it in MySQL. I want the idiot proof feature in MS SQL too :)

Comment: Any real dev /dba knows that chill when you run an update or a delete without the where clause on prod. There is always a microsecond between issuing the execute command and the cold, cold realization that you're gonna be restoring backups and hoping for the best in the next few hours :) Best practices aside, it's better if there is some intrinsic support for boneheaded users.

Comment: At Jamiec for most databases in the world, you will need the option of a human running some kind of ad-hoc query at some point, whether it's a dev or DBA. There really aren't any significant drawbacks to having a simple, optional, safety of some kind. If "just don't ever make mistakes" was a valid argument, we wouldn't need seatbelts and firearm safety switches .

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to set this for everybody, you can turn off SQL Server's autocommit functionality by turning IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS on. [See here](http://suneethasdiary.wordpress.com/tag/disabling-auto-commit-mode-in-sql-server-management-studio/).

If it is just you that you are concerned about, the above can be used in your session as well with `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`. Then you must actually call COMMIT to make anything stick. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx).

Comment: [This article](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-prevent-accidental-data-loss-from-executing-a-query-in-sql-server-aka-practicing-safe-coding/) demonstrates with screenshots the effect of this. The most important thing to note is that if there's someone else working on the same table and who is issuing a commit (implicitly or explicitly) on their (unrelated) transaction, then our uncommitted transaction will also be committed.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, you can always start a transaction before issuing the command, but without adding a `COMMIT` at the end. That way you can verify the query had the desired effect, and if so, manually issue a `COMMIT`. In case you made a mistake, simply issue a `ROLLBACK`.

You can also add triggers to the tables to prevent INSERTS or UPDATES from happening, but that would effect everyone and not just you.

The bottom line is that you should just never run untested queries on your production system ;) Use a snapshot copy of the database instead.

Comment: Usually, the commands I run against a production db are enclosed within a BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK TRAN block. But for the unwary user - who may have access to the db - the procedure is very risky.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said (MySQL safe update mode, restrict access to production, test first on a development server), it's not hard to train yourself to write an update statement like this in a SQL window.

```
update
set
where
```

Then backtrack to the top, and fill in the details.  This prevents you from omitting the WHERE clause, but it doesn't prevent you from writing a bad WHERE clause. I do this all the time now, even when I'm writing SQL in a SQL window on my local machine where the penalty for a bad update is nil.

The best thing to do is probably to write your SQL in <strike>emacs</strike> your text editor of choice, and program it to expand "UPDATE" to a partial statement with a WHERE clause.

Before anyone asks, I also write complex WHERE clauses like this.

```
where ()
```

followed by

```
where (() or ())
```

then by

```
where ((() and ()) or ())
```

Then I go back and fill in the conditions.

I picked up this habit years ago when I had to write a lot of code in C. It stems from training myself to write "if" statements like this. Omitted parens and braces caused other people a lot of headaches, so I eliminated that possibility.

```
if () {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about making a habit of always using:

```
UPDATE TOP (2) dbo.table set name = etc
```

Let's say you knew you only wanted to update 1 row. If you got back "2 rows affected", you know you made a typo, but at least you havn't destroyed the enire table.

Answer (score 0):

as other good practices said before: don't allow access to prod db, don't execute update without where; I add use different users and security policies for them. Maintain a good log so you can revert it just in case. An update on the whole table, depending of its size, may lock the whole table!